# Hosting .Net Core Web API to nginx (not proxying)

Tags: nginx, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

> I read articles which explains in detail about how to configure nginx as
>   reverse proxy for .net core Web APIs hosted on kestrel.
>
> I would like to know whether is it is possible to host a .Net Core WebAPI
>   directly on nginx so that there is not need for reverse proxy.

Comment: Check what is nginx and what it is capable of, and you should see why it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Request you to read this article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy
 this will clear that **you canNOT host ASP.NET Core Application directly on any web server be it IIS, NgInx or Apache.** You need to use these web servers as Reverse Proxy(Which is also a Very good Practice for Security and Performance point of view) with Kestrel as actual web server for .NET core applications.

**Kestrel is Mandatory for Hosting your .NET Core Web Application and your IIS, NGINX and Apache need to be setup as Reverse Proxy if you want.**

*In Short, it is not possible to use Nginx directly to Host ASP.NET Web API or MVC Apps.*